# Excel VBA Change Number format on Cell value change

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a little difficulty with some Excel visual basic.  Particularly I want to change the format of a column based on the value of a cell.  Here's what I have so far.

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Address = Range("$b$1") Then
        If Range("$b$1") = "Date" Then
            Range("d:d").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
        ElseIf Range("$b$1") = "Number" Then
            Range("d:d").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I am new to using the Target feature so any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you need to use Target, just the block inside that check should enough. Like this;

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Range("B1") = "Date" Then
        Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    ElseIf Range("B1") = "Number" Then
        Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "#,##0.00"
    End If

End Sub
```

Then change the value in B1 to "Date" or "Number".

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to tell if a particular cell or range of cells this code works

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
    <operations>
End If
```

This will trigger the < operations > ONLY if the target range intersects range A1.
If a macro runs and makes any change to the sheet the option to undo gets wiped out.

Hope this helps.